# not able to access uploaded media files in django

Tags: django

This is the error i am getting
[template does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nS1L.png)

This is my settings file [I have added media root and media directory in settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDS4k.png)

These are my urls [urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wcBt.png)

Comment: Share your `urls.py`? Seems like you have a catch-all path that is handling the request

Comment: added ss for urls.py as well

Comment: Please post actual code, not pictures. Is that your full `urls.py`? Can you post the full traceback, it would be handy to see the view that is triggering the error

Comment: just added this in my urls `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` it works

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `urls.py` file

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```